# Differnt counts for db.collection.count({}) and db.collection.count() in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 5.5 million records while doing a query like db.collection.count(), it is returning count as 5.5 million and while doing a query like db.collection.count({}), it is returning 5.2M.

Comment: Read the documentation. One reads from the collection stats and the other actually runs the "query" and returns the profiler result. This really "just happens" as the "stats" are an "estimate" of what is believed to be tracked and the "query" is what is definitely there. Been answered here before I'm certain.

Comment: Before anyone gets pedantic about the duplicate question title, "read the opening paragraph in the answer" which points out that `find().count()` and `.count(query)` are different to `count()`. And really just links to the documentation and pulls out paragraphs from it. `</end_rant>`